# Attempting to install "ros-melodic-desktop-full" fails due to dependency "ros-build-tools" v.0.3.2

Tags: linux, archlinux, arch

I am trying to install the “ros-melodic-desktop-full" package from the Arch AUR by following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/ArchLinux

Among the various dependencies on which this package depends, it also requires the “ros-build-tools" package. The latest version in the AUR repository of this package is version 0.3.2. In this version the maintainer removed the “fix-python-scripts.sh” script which is required by earlier versions of “ros-melodic-desktop-full" (the package I’m trying to install). The deletion of this script causes the installation process to fail and the commit which I am referring to can be found here:

https://github.com/ros-arch/ros-build-tools/commit/be4af0472a1cecf8bcd6554d165f9557d9499c04#diff-c13dbcca92f9ff12cd26ecce958be3f9ee8563baace04f7a463a6d2dd4252e0bL20

The deleted script "fix-python-scripts.sh" is required by the build pipeline of "ros-melodic-desktop-full" and it can be checked on line 44 here:

https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ros-melodic-desktop-full#n44

Installing an earlier version (v 0.3.1) of this package (“ros-build-tools"), might solve the problem but I am reluctant to use it. What alternatives do I have? How may I install this package?